# putting a small program in a string in an array

Tags: java, arrays

im kinda new to programming and i made this small programm with a question and i have got a few other questions following that one, the thing is that i want to put it in an array. now from what i have understood i have to put it in a string to then put it in a array with the rest of my questions. i put the code from one of the question so you guys can tell me if what im asking is even possible :) thanks!

I want to ask the user a number of questions. If I have only one question, the code would look like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Bycicle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int num1;
        // first question
        System.out.println("\n is the bycicle moving? : ");
        System.out.println("1 : yes.");
        System.out.println("2 : no.");
        System.out.flush();
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
        if (num1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("\n good, keep going");
        } else if (num1 == 2) {
            System.out.println("\n get a move on then!\n \n \n END");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I put a number of questions and answers into an array?

Comment: what do you want to put in array? What exactly do you want?

Comment: 1. Please format your code properly. 2. Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Your explanation is very unclear. Can you try to clarify it, elaborate a bit and possible add an example of how you want it to work?

Comment: Before putting question into array you'll have to put your own question in our head first.

Comment: I've read this a few times and I have no idea what you are looking for, in terms of input, expected result and what is actually wrong in the first place. The formatting is hurting my eyes too, can you clear this question up and we'll jump on it?!

Comment: By the way, it's `bicycle` not `bycicle`

Comment: sorry if it was unclear... i have a series of questions like that one (i only put that one so that it wouldn't be too long) and i would like each one of my questions to be in one array, so that the code would look  more sorted. sorry if my code is wrong but i'm a beginner and porting it to the website messed it up a bit i think :/

Comment: @jeanking, if you have a series of questions like this, then, 1. Create a Question class. 2. Create an ArrayList of Question in Bicycle class 3. Iterate through the list till your questions end

Comment: so do i even have to put it in a string to put it in my array, or can i just put my code in my array just like that by using an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are programming **Object** oriented, you schould make a Question class.

```java
public class Question{
    private String question
    private String answer

    //getter & setter here
}
```

Now in your `main` methode:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Question[] questions = new Question[2];
    questions[0] = new Question("Is this bicycle moving?","yes");
    questions[0] = new Question("Does this eagel fly","yes");
    // and so on
}
```

You can iterate over the Questions with [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

**Edit:**
Example for iteration

```
for(Question question : questions){
    System.out.println(question.question)
    //now read the input and use equals to verify it 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Question` class as follows,

```
class Question{

   public Question(String questionStatement, String answer){
      this.questionStatement = questionStatement;
      this.answer = answer;
   }
   String questionStatement;
   String answer;
   // whatever fields you want here for a question e.g. options, answers.
   // getters and setters for all fields
}
```

In your `Bicycle` class,create `List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();`

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    questions.add(new Question("does this Bicycle move?","yes"))
    // add many questions in the list here

    for(Question question : questions){
        // do whatever you want to ask questions and get answer
    }

}
```

Comment: yes but the problem is that somewhere in my questions, i have added a for loop, which i don't think i could be able to put i a question, right?

Comment: `ArrayList<Answer> answers` might be a better than `String answer` (with `Answer` containing what the answer is and what it should print or do).

Comment: @Dukeling, yeah thats why I wrote answers or options in comments.

Comment: @jeanking, you don't need to put for loop in a question. You need to iterate the list of questions